# Other than coding the whole method, can I use an in-built function in C++ to find the most occurring element in an array?

Tags: c++

I have an array `v = [5,1,5,4,5,2,3,4,5,6,5]`. I want to return the most frequently occurring value, which is 5 in this case. Is there an in-built function in C++ for the same?

I can implement a method to calculate the frequency of each element thereby returning the value with maximum frequency but I would very much like to know if there is a better way to do the same.

Comment: Hardly a duplicate. He is asking if a built in exists, not how to do it. Different question altogether.

Comment: The short answer is: "no, there isn't." There  are primitives you can use to build it a bit more easily, but no function to do that specific job on its own.

Comment: @Taekahn It doesn't seem to me that it's useful to keep this open as a "yes/no" question. If there is a built-in algorithm to do this, it should be added as an answer to the target, and the target also allows for alternative solutions.

Comment: @Taekahn I'm a she :P. Also, thank you for pointing out that it's a different question. I have been getting notifications that it is similar to various other questions, therefore I should review whereas I'm still trying to understand how they are the same. I'm a new user to stack overflow, still learning about the platform!

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks for letting me know! That answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::unordered_map` container with `std::max_element` function to find most frequent element in an array or vector. For instance:

```
int getMostFrequentElement(vector<int> &arr)
{
    if (arr.empty())
        return -1;

    unordered_map<int, int> freq_count;

    for (const auto &item : arr)
        freq_count[item]++;


    auto most_freq_int =
            std::max_element(freq_count.begin(), freq_count.end(),
                 [] (const auto &x, const auto &y) {return x.second < y.second;});

    return most_freq_int->first;
}
```